# Using the package `rintrojs` breaks the display of panels in a navbarPage

Tags: r, shiny, intro.js

I'm trying to do a presentation of my shiny app with the package `rintrojs`. This works well when I use it on `actionButton` or things like that but I would like to use it on the names of tabPanels.

I don't want to present something display in the panels, I want to have an intro box on the name of the panels. However, when doing this, the tabPanels do not display anymore. How should I do it?

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(rintrojs)

ui <- navbarPage(

  title = "foo",
  introjsUI(),
  tabPanel(
    introBox(title = "Panel 1",
             data.step = 1,
             data.intro = "This is Panel 1"),
    fluidRow(actionButton("button1", "Button 1"))
  ), 

  tabPanel(
    introBox(title = "Panel 2",
             data.step = 2,
             data.intro = "This is Panel 2"),
    fluidRow(actionButton("button2", "Button 2"))
  )

  # If you want to see a "normal" app, comment from "introjsUI()" to here, and uncomment the chunk below 
  # tabPanel(title = "Panel 1",
  #          fluidRow(actionButton("button1", "Button 1"))
  # ),
  # tabPanel(title = "Panel 2",
  #          fluidRow(actionButton("button2", "Button 2"))
  # )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  introjs(session)

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer provided [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-the-package-rintrojs-breaks-the-display-of-panels-in-a-navbarpage/51278/2):

```
library(shiny)
library(rintrojs)

ui <- navbarPage(

  title = "foo",
  introjsUI(),
  tabPanel(
    title = introBox("Panel 1",
             data.step = 1,
             data.intro = "This is Panel 1"),
    fluidRow(actionButton("button1", "Button 1"))
  ), 

  tabPanel(
    title = introBox("Panel 2",
             data.step = 2,
             data.intro = "This is Panel 2"),
    fluidRow(actionButton("button2", "Button 2"))
  )

  # If you want to see a "normal" app, comment from "introjsUI()" to here, and uncomment the chunk below 
  # tabPanel(title = "Panel 1",
  #          fluidRow(actionButton("button1", "Button 1"))
  # ),
  # tabPanel(title = "Panel 2",
  #          fluidRow(actionButton("button2", "Button 2"))
  # )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  introjs(session)

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```